# why imagemagick and gd get picture Pixels are different？

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, gif

I hava picture?The picture format is gif.

```
<?php
    $animation = new Imagick('1.gif');
    echo $animation->getImageWidth();
    echo "\n";
    echo $animation->getImageHeight();
?>
```

return `70 124`;

```
<?php
    $a = getimagesize('1.gif');
    echo ($a[3]);
?>
```

return `width="160" height="217"`;
I try other gif picture,the result is same.

Comment: Which one is correct?

Comment: @Salman A :In firefox,display 160x217,but in windows,display 70x24

Comment: @Salman A:What's the mean that there is a problem between the chair and keyboard?

Comment: @Salman A:And I don't agree with that you said the image coule be broken

Comment: Is that an animated GIF?

Comment: @Salman A:Yes,the picture is animated GIF